# Error while using DateTime.parseextract

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have a textbox - DateOfBirth
I follow following steps from validating data to saving it in database.

Step 1: When I submit text, I validate if date is in correct format(dd/mm/yyyy):

```
string Pattern = @"^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/](0?[1-9]|1[012])[/](19|20)\d\d";
```

Step 2: If format is correct, I convert input value of textbox to datetime format:

```
IFormatProvider theCultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB", true);
DOB = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDOB.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy", theCultureInfo);
```

Step 3: Then I send value to database and save as it is in my table.

I got an issue here:
For date "04/04/2012" everything works fine.
But if I submit date "4/04/2012" or "04/4/2012", the step 2 throws an exception:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

How do I handle this issue ?

Should I escape step 2 and do conversion in database query instead ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because the method expects that you have two places for the date and you only supplied one value, so to solve your problem, remove one `d` in `ParseExact` format.

```
IFormatProvider theCultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB", true);
DOB = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDOB.Value, "d/M/yyyy", theCultureInfo);
```

Comment: @user1820973 No no, `"d/m/yyyy"` still means Days/Minutes/Years. You must use `"d/M/yyyy"` instead, or you might get strange errors.